# Image sometimes does not appear in push notification

Tags: android, node.js, ruby-on-rails, react-native, push-notification

When developing an application, an external service was implemented for sending push notifications, all pushes sent must have a title, text and image, however, images appear randomly in push notifications or not. Images of different dimensions were tested and sometimes they appear on push and sometimes they don't. Any idea what can be done to help identify and fix the notifications issue?

Tests done on: android 12

Image: 520x470 => 393.8kB

**Service that sends the push:**

- Ruby 2.7.1
- Rails 6.0.3.3
- command-line-args: 5.2.1
- firebase-admin: 10.0.2

```
fork do
   exec(
     "node #{path} --tokens #{token} --title #{title} --message #{msg} --link '#{url}' --id #{id} --image #{img}"
   )
end
```

The image path is sent as a string

App:
React Native v0.66.3

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("./app-name-c0529a8230hq.json");

const cli = require("./cli")();

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://app-name.firebaseio.com"
});

const payload = {
  tokens: cli.tokens.split(','),
  notification: {
    body: cli.message,
    title: cli.title,
  },
  data: {
    openURL: cli.link,
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        'mutable-content': 1,
      },
    },
    fcm_options: {
      image: cli.image,
    },
  },
  android: {
    notification: {
      image: cli.image,
    },
  },
};

admin
  .messaging()
  .sendMulticast(payload)
  .then((s) => {
      console.log('Success: ', s);
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log("Error", e))
```

Thanks for any idea to help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If image have to be downloaded locally maybe the problem is the image size, perhaps is too big for network connection. It also could be the image file extention (PNG or JPEG are allowed), or the image resolution.

In other hand, if you're working with android, it could have different behaviours depending on how you build the notification json and if the android app is background or not.

What if you try the payload adding

```
 image: cli.image,
```

to notification, this way:

```
 notification: {
    body: cli.message,
    title: cli.title,
    image: cli.image,
  },
```